# How to make a Search section in html and search view in django with multiple queries

Tags: python, django

I am trying to do car sale webpage (educational purpose) and i found out how to make a search but i want to make it look better as it is in many car sale pages with section where it is possible to choose car categories, fuel type, damaged or not etc. 
my search view for now is this:

```py
    def search(request):
        if 'search_filter' in request.GET:
            search_filter = request.GET['search_filter']
            cars = [{
                'id': x.id,
                'driven': x.driven,
                'description': x.description,
                'price': x.price,
                'firstImage': x.carimage_set.first().image
            } for x in Car.objects.filter(description__icontains=search_filter)
            ]
            return JsonResponse({'data': cars})
        context = {'cars': Car.objects.all().order_by('price')}
        return render(request, 'cars/car_index.html', context)
```

Now, this perform search if it finds in the description, what I am looking. My goal is to make it so the user can enter the values that wants to search in the input box, like car type, car make, year etc.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<form action="">
<select name="cars">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="fiat">Fiat</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>

    <legend>Additional Info:</legend>
    Car Type:<br>
    <input type="text" name="car_type">
    <br>
    Car Make:<br>
    <input type="text" name="car_make">
    <br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Search">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

This is a very primitive form, but this is my idea of how i am trying to make it look like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Q objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects).

Use a hidden field so that you know when to perform search.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<form method="get">
<select name="cars">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="fiat">Fiat</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>

    <legend>Additional Info:</legend>
    Car Type:<br>
    <input type="text" name="car_type">
    <br>
    Car Make:<br>
    <input type="text" name="car_make">
    <br><br>
    <input type="hidden" name="search_filter" value="true">
    <input type="submit" value="Search">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Your view will be something like this:

```
import operator

def search(request):
        if 'search_filter' in request.GET:  # set a hidden field (search_filter) so you know that you need to perform a search
            search_params = request.GET.dict()
            search_params.pop("search_filter")
            # for all search params which are not null, create a Q object
            # assuming that you provide the column name as search criteria.
            q_list = [Q(("{}__icontains".format(param), search_params[param])) for param in search_params if search_params[param] is not None]  

            queryset = Car.objects.filter(reduce(operator.and_, q_list))  # combine Q object using & operation
            cars = [{
                'id': x.id,
                'driven': x.driven,
                'description': x.description,
                'price': x.price,
                'firstImage': x.carimage_set.first().image
            } for x in queryset
            ]
            return JsonResponse({'data': cars})
        context = {'cars': Car.objects.all().order_by('price')}
        return render(request, 'cars/car_index.html', context)
```

For more options and control over filters, you can use [django-filters](https://github.com/carltongibson/django-filter)

Comment: i get the query but when i print the queryset i don't see it in the console.

Comment: what seems to be the issue? no result? wrong query?

Comment: i can see the query get builded in the url, `FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'search_filter into field. Choices are:....` and when i print the contex, or search_params it seems that it never comes there, I dont understand if the problem is at my model or where, i know this might sound so obscure but any hint or tip of where i need to look for this problem would be very helpful.

Comment: oh..just remove the `search_filter` from the `search_params` dict. This is because `search_filter` is not really a column.

Comment: thanks, i am doing progress, but now i have another error. Object of type CarCategory is not JSON serializable.

Comment: where exactly are you using the category, and how are you using it. get the `__str__` or an other field from the `CarCategory` object and it should work fine

Comment: `class CarCategory(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name` This my CarCategory and as you can see it returns self.name, but still get the error. Good thing is that it returns correct data, in the queryset, but the problem seems to be at serialization of json, because when i enter to search something that does not exist, it returns an empty json, and not any error.

Comment: queryset will give you the object. In order to deconstruct the object into string, you should use `{"carcategory": x.carcategory.name}`

Comment: That's correct, it took me a little to understand but finally i did it, thank you very much for your help.